# DotNetBrowser memory limits?

Tags: dotnetbrowser

I have a problem with DotNetBrowser and some memory hungry web pages.

Looking at dotnetbrowser-chromium32.exe in windows process monitor, every pages that allocate more than 800 Mb are interrupted and the browser control becomes black.

For example, this code reaches the limit generating a large random string array:

```
<body>
    <script>
        function randomString() {
            var chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
            var string_length = 800;
            var randomstring = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < string_length; i++) {
                var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
                randomstring += chars.substring(rnum, rnum + 1);
            }
            return randomstring;
        }

        var COUNT = 60000
        var list = []
        for (var i = 0; i < COUNT; i++) {
            list.push(randomString())
        }
        document.body.innerText="Memory test completed."
    </script>
</body>
```

There’s a way to allow more memory usage and avoid the problem ?

Thanks you

Comment: Could you please add a link to the web page for which this behavior is reproducible?

Comment: I've added to the post some sample code. Thanks